# Index file for searching is large

Tags: python, json, algorithm, indexing, full-text-search

I have written an algorithm in python for indexing every word in ~500 text files (some are larger than 2 MB) to use in a search engine for my app. The index file is json-based, i.e. {key:value} structure. The data indexed are: file ID, paragraph ID, and line number. This is done for every word. Similar words are combined.

Problem is the index file turned to be relatively large (more than twice as row data), and this will increase the size of my app. The app is used without internet, so index file must be shipped within.

It is my first time to mess with such things, so I wonder if there is a way to reduce the size by, say, using other databases structures than json, optimal format to put the index file, or anything else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can check my suggestion

Comment: Paragraph ID seems redundant. It can be inferred from file ID and line number. Also, do you ship raw data with the app?

Comment: @user58697 It is a poetry app, I meant by paragraph the poem. It should be indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON structure is a good choice , but to not make your app large , you can use a distributed system for indexation .

I mean that **you can create many indexation files** instead of one , and you can write an algorithm which will search within them in a distributed way

And about size problem , you can compress them , and decompress each indexation file only for searching

---

*Example :*

Index files : f1 , f2 , f3

*They will be compressed and stored in your app , and to search here is what you can do :*

```
for f in f1 , f2 , f3 :
    index_file = decompress(f)
    # search within index_file
```

Comment: What do you mean by distributed system?

Comment: @Ali_Habeeb its a system which works with components that are located in different computers or networks ( or different nodes in same computer ) , in your case its a distributed algorithm in the same computer , i suggested you the following solution because i'll be better to compress many files of 1 MB than one file of 2 MB or more ( it'll make you reduce more memory )

Comment: I will give it a try.

Comment: @Ali_Habeeb Good luck

Answer (score 0):

you should check this module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#module-pickle

Comment: It says it is not human readable, and it is python-specific. My app is written in Swift lang. JSON is human readable.